# How to know what is the frequency of our data and how to make choice of which model is best for our data to forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a data for each minute as shown below

`Timestamp          cpu-usage
2017-02-14 00:00:00  1.80000
2017-02-14 00:01:00 16.04000
2017-02-14 00:02:00 23.16000
2017-02-14 00:03:00 24.21400
2017-02-14 00:04:00 24.74100
2017-02-14 00:05:00 12.88767`

I have created a graph for this data

```
>plot(data.ts)
```

[image]

I have even plot Correlation plot for this

```
>acf((log(data.ts)))
```

[image]

```
>pacf((log(data.ts)))
```

Now by seeing the above graphs, how can I make sure that my data is stationary or not. And also how to apply model for forecasting. Which model is best for this data. How to get the frequency for this.

Comment: I need clarification. The graph shows one day worth of data by minute. There are ten peaks from 0:00 to 2:30, so about one peak every 15 minutes. In the ACF graph, I'm seeing labels of 500 and 1000, so is that x axis in seconds?  If so, it looks like you need to "seasonally" difference your data by 15 minutes and see if that improves your graphs.